# Ler arquivo .txt, enviar Linha e Apaga-la após confirmação de recebimento

Tags: c#, funções

Esse codigo é o fragmento de um metodo que faz a leitura de um arquivo de texto e envia seu conteudo linha por linha, onde a cada linha enviada recebe uma confirmação de recebimento. Gostaria de apagar do arquivo a linha enviada assim obtiver sua confirmação de recebimento, de modo que, caso a transmissao seja interrompida no meio do arquivo, eu não envie as linhas que já foram enviadas, evitando assim duplicar a informação recebida pelo equipamento. Algúem poderia me ajudar com isso ?

```
 //Path ex : "/home/dhnqe/DataContainer.txt"
  if (File.Exists(path))
  {
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
    int numeroLinhas = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length;
    while ((linha = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        linha = string.Format(linha + "\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
        {
        controle = false;
        SendLineByRadio(address, line); //Enviar Linha
        int start = Environment.TickCount;
        do
        {
          ...
          ...
        } while (!controle && !timeout);

        if (controle)
        {
            if (Confirmation == "ReceiveOK")//Caso receba a confirmação
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data Sent  = OK");
                clearData();
                controle = false;
                //INSERIR FUNCAO PARA APAGAR LINHA ENVIADA DO ARQUIVO TXT
                i = 10;
            }
        }
        if (timeout)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data Sent = Confirmation Timeout");//Caso não recebe a confirmacao
            clearData();
            controle = true;
            if (i == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Response not received");
                clearData();
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            }

        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Você precisa apagar as linhas? Isso não é muito eficiente. A confirmação é síncrona? i.e. você só envia uma linha do arquivo quando confirmou a anterior? Se sim, porque não guardar apenas o numero da ultima linha enviada num outro arquivo temporário ex:DataContainer.txt.tmp ? No final, você apaga os dois. Assim você recupera o estado caso interrompa a execução da aplicção.

Comment: É que quando uma linha é enviada o programa espera por uma mensagem do destinatário confirmando seu recebimento, casa não receba confirmação a transmissão é abortada.

Comment: Porém, por exemplo, caso houvesse um arquivo com 10 linhas e a transmissão fosse abortada na quinta linha o destinatário ja havia recebido as quatro anteriores, e nesse caso se eu envia-las novamente um uma outra requisição de transmissão, ele iria conter informação duplicada, uma vez que o destino armazena todas informações transferidas.

Comment: Como pode ser visto também no código, esse metodo é executado por uma nova Thread sempre que há uma requisição de comunicação, a qual é abortada caso não receba confirmação do recebimento da linha.

Comment: A idéia do arquivo temporário pode funcionar, vou tentar implementar aqui e testar, retornarei sobre isso

Comment: Ok, alterar um arquivo sobre o qual está iterando não é muito boa ideia. Você não tem controle sobre o servidor para onde envia as informações? Se uma linha foi recebida e a confirmação não chegou, como você sabe? nesse caso vai reenviar a informação, o ideal era ter um protocolo para evitar essas situações.

Comment: Sim existe um protocolo onde, eu Envio a linha e espero uma Mensagem de Confirmação com um timeout, se estourar esse timeout a linha é reenviada, isso acontece 3 vezes, caso não recebe a resposta o processo é finalizado e o dispositivo precisa fazer outra requisição de transmissão. Essa transmissão é feita por Radio Frequência, o destino é um equipamento microcontrolado, então a unica forma de saber se a linha recebeu é com a mensagem mesmo.

Comment: Pensei também em ler o arquivo e criar uma lista com as linhas e ao passo que cada linha é enviada eu apago sua entrada, caso a transmissão tenha que ser abortada, eu reescrevo o arquivo com as linhas que sobraram

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668907/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: valeu galera, o arquivo temporario funcionou, segue a resposta para que ajude alguem futuramente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom galera a resposta encontrada foi criar a variavel `lineCounter` para contar as linhas enviadas com sucesso

```
   //Path ex : "/home/dhnqe/DataContainer.txt"
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
      int lineCount = 0; // VARIAVEL CRIADA PARA CONTAR AS LINHAS ENVIADAS
      StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
      int numeroLinhas = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length;
      while ((linha = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
          linha = string.Format(linha + "\r\n");
          for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
          {
          controle = false;
          SendLineByRadio(address, line); //Enviar Linha
          int start = Environment.TickCount;
          do
          {
            ...
            ...
          } while (!controle && !timeout);

          if (controle)
          {
              if (Confirmation == "ReceiveOK")//Caso receba a confirmação
              {
                  lineCount++; //INCREMENTAR, POIS A LINHA FOI ENVIADA E A RESPOSTA FOI RECEBIDA
                  Console.WriteLine("Data Sent  = OK");
                  clearData();
                  controle = false;
                 i = 10;
              }
          }
          if (timeout)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Data Sent = Confirmation Timeout");//Caso não recebe a confirmacao
              clearData();
              controle = true;
              if (i == 2)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Error: Response not received");
                  clearData();
                  Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
              }

          }
       }
     }
```

A Partir da Variavel a funcao `ApagarLinhas()` Le o arquivo e copia as linhas que nao foram criadas para um arquivo temporário, em seguida substitui o arquivo pelo original, apagando em seguida o arquivo de backup.

```
  private void ApagarLinhas(string fileInput,int line_to_keep)
      {
        string line = null;
        int line_number = 0;
        string tempFile = fileInput + ".tmp";
        string backupFile = fileInput+"backup";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileInput))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
            {
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line_number++;

                    if (line_number <= line_to_keep)
                        continue;

                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        File.Replace(tempFile, fileInput, backupFile);
        File.Delete(backupFile);                 

      }
```